# Faulty '/0' returning in C program

Tags: c

My current code outputs an extra dot and fails a test case I'm trying to pass:

[image]

I realize that having extra input in my output implies that I didn't put the closing '\0' in the correct location. Here's my code:

```c
else if (isdigit(c))
{
    value[0] = (char)c;
    c = fgetc(input);
    int count = 0;
    int index = 1;
    bool isRealNumber = false;

    while (isdigit(c) || c == '.') 
    {
        if (c == '.') 
        {
            isRealNumber = true;
            c = fgetc(input);

            if (c == '.')
            {
                value[index] = '.';
                index++; 
                value[index + 1] = '\0';
                c = ungetc(c, input);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                value[index] = '.';
                index++;
                value[index + 1] = '\0';
            }
        }
        value[index] = (char)c;
        c = fgetc(input);
        count += 1;
        index += 1;
    }
    c = ungetc(c, input);

    if (isRealNumber)
        T.id = SQL_REAL_LITERAL;
    else
        T.id = SQL_INT_LITERAL;

    T.line = *lineNumber;
    T.col = *colNumber;

    *colNumber = *colNumber + count + 1;

    value[index] = '\0';

    return T;
}
```

I've tried setting my null value ('\0') as one before but it failed to fix anything.

Comment: You seem to be calling `fgetc` too often.  If `c =='.'`, you set `isReadNumber` to true and then read another value.  If that next value is also `.`, I would call that a syntax error.  `5..6` does not look like a valid input to me.

Comment: It is a valid input in the test case we have for a class D: It's supposed to read 5. as a real number, then . as a separate token (just a dot), then six as an integer number.

Comment: `/0` should be `\0`.

Comment: I only have '\0's in my code, no '/0' ... typo at the end of my post there.

Answer (score 0):

Revealed after indenting your code: In case of two consecutive dots you have two `ungetc()`. The standard guarantees for "unget" only one character, and your system seems to follow this.